# Return rows that have the same value in one column but the column value is unknown

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset called `pop` and want to return the only 2 rows that have the same value in column 'J'. I do not know what rows have the same value and do not know what the common value is... I want to return these two rows.

Without knowing the common value, this code is not helpful:

```
pop.loc[pop['X'] == some_value]
```

I tried this but it returned the entire dataset:

```
pop.query('X' == 'X')
```

Any input is appreciated...

Comment: show your example dataset and the example you want

Answer (score 1):

You can do [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) then get the first element, which has been sorted to be the most common value.

I'll use some dummy data here:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'f'], columns=['X'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   X
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  b
5  f

In [4]: wanted_value = df['X'].value_counts().index[0]

In [5]: wanted_value
Out[5]: 'b'

In [6]: df[df['X'] == wanted_value]
Out[6]: 
   X
1  b
4  b
```

For reference, `df['X'].value_counts()` is:

```
b    2
a    1
c    1
d    1
f    1
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -4):

Thanks, I figured out another way that seemed a bit easier...

pop['X'].value_counts()

- the top value was 21 and showed '2', indicating 21 was the duplicated value; all remaining values indicated '1', no duplicates

pop.loc[pop['X'] == 21]

- returned the 2 rows with the duplicated value in column X.

Comment: This is the exact same as my solution except that you're doing the `.index[0]` step manually and you're using `.loc` instead of bare indexing (which does the same thing). Please don't post duplicate answers. Also, if you're using someone else's work, [you have to give credit](/help/referencing). BTW, please add the library tag to the question like I asked.

Comment: I am really new to this so apologize for not using the site properly, so new that I do note even understand that our codes are similar. As far as giving credit, it does not see if I looked up how to use value_counts() or .loc (and the others I tried) in a book or online and then figuring out how to apply it to my problem requires giving credit. The code is not cut/paste and seems basic as well. If it does require credit, it seems we all should give credit for everything out here. Pandas library tag done... Thanks!

Comment: Well, what I mean is, you wrote *"Thanks, I figured out another way that seemed a bit easier"*, which looks like a reply to my answer, then you explain a solution that's practically the same as mine, which makes it look like you copied my solution (knowingly or not). Anyway, I'm not accusing you of plagiarism, just saying, *if you are* copying, here's what you should do. The more important thing is that this duplicates my answer, so there's no need to post it separately. If anything's unclear in my answer, I'd be happy to clarify it, just leave a comment there.

Comment: OOPS!!! Really sorry... I see now that what I thought was different is pretty much the same! In short I misunderstood the whole thing above about dummy data, etc above... Sorry about all this...